# How can I center the text in the headers for an AG-grid control?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How can I center the text in the headers for an AG-grid control? I have tried using cellstyle and cellclass in the column definition but that did not work. Thank you

Comment: also .ag-header-cell is set to  text-align: center

Comment: See, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933672/right-align-column-headers-in-aggrid for an answer that worked.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'm using React and I just added the following snippet to my Table component's `.css`

```css
.ag-header-cell-label {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I'm overriding the `.css` class class from `ag-grid` which I found via devtools inspection, and discovered it's using flexbox for display.

See example (not react but same concept): https://embed.plnkr.co/O3NI4WgHxkFiJCyacn0r/

Comment: What If I want to center text of selected header? Any ideias? How can I get a class from a specific column header?

Comment: Beautiful!  Thx.

Comment: You can set a style for a specific header column by setting the headerClass for that column's definition. You might also need to use !important in the style class definition if it needs to override properties that are already defined on the header via the existing ag-grid classes.

Answer (score 21):

You may use this property:

```
cellStyle: {textAlign: 'center'}
```

Comment: this does not affect the header. i tried `headerClass` and `headerCellClass` so far no luck..

Comment: This is for cells, not headers

Answer (score 9):

A more complete solution I've been using for a while now, is to create a column definition helper like this:

```js
export const columnCentered = {
  headerClass: 'text-center',
  cellStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    // Add the following if you are using .ag-header-cell-menu-button 
    // and column borders are set to none.
    // marginLeft: '-16px'
  }
}
```

then add the following to your `style.scss`

```
.ag-header-cell.text-center {
  .ag-header-cell-label {
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

finally you can easily use it like this:

```js
columnDefs: [
  { field: 'normalCol' },
  { field: 'centeredColA' ...columnCentered },
  { field: 'centeredColB' ...columnCentered }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to align your text right, left or center in ag-grid. Then use this:-

```
cellStyle: { textAlign: 'right' }
cellStyle: { textAlign: 'left' } 
cellStyle: { textAlign: 'center' }
```

Comment: This just aligns the cell text but not the header text

Answer (score 6):

To use a custom class, add `headerClass: "text-center"` to the column definition and css as follows:

```
text-center * {
    justifyContent: center
}
```

Comment: Just a note,its justify-content: center

Answer (score 5):

Assign a class to the cell as below:

```
gridOptions = {
  ...
  columnDefs: [
    ...
        { headerName: "field1", field: "field1", cellClass: "grid-cell-centered"}
    ...
  ]
}
```

css file:

```
.grid-cell-centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: i have a feeling this will only center the content of the cell and not the header

Answer (score 2):

For (independent) customization of each header, you can make a custom header component: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Angular 8 and AG-Grid is nested deep in some other component.

I had to do this in order to make it work.

```
.ag-header-group-cell-label {
      justify-content: center !important;
}
```

And, this strictly needs to be under `styles.scss` file and not in the component scss file. Or else, it will not work.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: in component scss file:

:host ::ng-deep .ag-header-cell-label {
    justify-content: center !important;
}

Comment: ::ng-deep is being deprecated, just set component's ViewEncapsulation.None and your style works.

Answer (score 2):

My CSS:

```
/*HEADER STYLE*/
        .ag-theme-alpine .ag-header-cell {
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }
        
        .ag-right-header .ag-header-cell-label {
             flex-direction: row-reverse;
        }
    
        .ag-center-header .ag-header-cell-label {
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .ag-left-header .ag-header-cell-label {
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .ag-center-cell {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .ag-right-cell {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .ag-left-cell {
            text-align: left;
        }
```

And use inside columnDefs:

```
{
                headerName: 'header_name',
                field: 'header_field',
                headerClass: "ag-center-header",
                cellClass: "ag-center-cell"
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
.ag-header-cell-label {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by overriding the css like:-

```
    ::ng-deep .ag-header-group-cell-label {
      justify-content: center !important;
    }
    
    ::ng-deep .ag-header-cell-label {
      justify-content: center !important;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using angular and I just want to center text in the grouped header so use this code to style.css

```
.ag-header-group-cell-label {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Your answer has been included [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62811934/6670491)

Answer (score 0):

columndef has a property. headerClass: '', you can add css to header

Answer (score 0):

```
:host ::ng-deep .my-center-header-class .ag-header-cell-text {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Set headerClass as 'my-center-header-class' in colDef