# Right align column headers in AgGrid

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to right-align the column headers in the AgGrid. I know how to do this implementing a custom header component using [IHeaderAngularComp](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#header-group-component) and supplying my own template however that seems like a lot of work for something that should be trivial.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-ebvgjb

[Align price column heading to right to match alignment with cell contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtsWn.png)

I am using the following libraries.

"ag-grid-angular": "21.2.1"

"ag-grid-community": "21.2.1"

Comment: a MVCE stackblitz would make it easier to help

Comment: @AkberIqbal Added stackblitz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to make these 2 changes to the **css** file to make it happen... since there is a little burger menu which gets visible on hover also.

```
::ng-deep .ag-cell-label-container{flex-direction: row}
::ng-deep .ag-header-cell-label { flex-direction: row-reverse; }
```

Forked your [stackblitz with this change here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-qwnkzb)

Comment: Thanks, buddy. Simplest solution I've seen yet. This is a slight modification to the Stack blitz to restrict the right alignment to the numeric Price column only. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-hzqdnw

Comment: @Imran ... thanks for the stackblitz link ... I was banging my head for 3 days was not able to align a couple of headers to left and right in combination. thanks a lot. God bless you.

Answer (score 10):

If you want all column headers to align right:

```
defaultColDef: { headerClass: "ag-right-aligned-header"}
```

If you want a single column header to align right:

```
{ headerName: "name", field: "field", headerClass: "ag-right-aligned-header" }
```

Answer (score 1):

[working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-bmjnsk)
fixed by defining template in headerComponentParams.

Comment: Thanks, the issue I have with this is that the sort/filtering no longer works out of the box and you have to implement in your custom template.Which seems like an overhead for a trivial ask.

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking to align some of the numeric columns to the right and other columns to left, you might want to check this link (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-hzqdnw ) posted by @Imran in the comment section of the correct answer.