# Ag-Grid Header Align Center is not Working - Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using Angular 9 and installed package [ag-grid-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-angular) & [ag-grid-community](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ag-grid-community/all-modules).

I want to align: center the Headers of my Table. [Please refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obPnv.png)

I referred [these stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490177/how-can-i-center-the-text-in-the-headers-for-an-ag-grid-control) but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Referring to override ag-grid styles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52672411/4483102)

You need to use this part :

```
  styles:[`
      .ag-header-group-cell-label { justify-content: center; }
      .ag-header-cell-label { justify-content: center; }
  `],
```

`ag-header-group-cell-label` - for grouped headers

`ag-header-cell-label` - for normal headers

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://plnkr.co/edit/aQ0bXfQCifiK8uj5)

Comment: I just added in the css file of particular component & It's working... Thank You

Comment: If the above does'nt work, try this

:host ::ng-deep .ag-header-cell-label {
  justify-content: center;
}